# Modify dynamic array through functions

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I've been having some trouble dealing with dynamic arrays... in the next code I try to put every digit of `n` to an array called `digitList`. It works OK because I can print every value in the array from CALL 1 (inside the `createDigitList` function), but I cannot from the main. What am I doing wrong???

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n = 1234;
    int *digitList;

    createDigitList(n, digitList);
//CALL 2 PRINTF
    printf("Call 2: %d \n", digitList[2]);

    return 0;
}

//returns number of digits (works OK)
int nDigits(int n) {
    int unit;
    int digit = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        unit = n % 10;
        n = (n - unit )/ 10;
        digit++;
    }
    return digit;
}

//Allocates memory for list and puts every digit inside the array list
void createDigitList(int n, int list[]) {
    int digit, i;
    list = (int*) malloc(nDigits(n)*sizeof(int));
    for (i = nDigits(n)-1; i >=0; i--) {
        digit = n % 10;
        list[i] = digit;
        n = (n - digit )/ 10;

    }
//CALL 1 PRINTF
    printf("Call 1: %d \n", list[2]);
}
```

Output:

```
Call 1: 3
Call 2: -2063401279
```

Thank you in advance to you all!

Comment: `list` is local to your function, so changing it will not effect the `digitList` in main, thats still an uninitialized pointer

Comment: tenigram, `//returns number of digits (works OK)
int nDigits(int n)` --> Hmmm, what would you expect `nDigits(0)` to  return?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the pointer `digitList` by reference to the function  `createDigitList`

```
createDigitList(n, &digitList);
```

Otherwise the function will deal with a copy of the pointer. Changing the copy does not influence on the original pointer.

The function itself should be declared at least like

```
int createDigitList(int n, int **list) {
    int digit, i;
    *list = (int*) malloc(nDigits(n)*sizeof(int));
    //  and so on
```

The function should return the size of the allocated array. Otherwise the caller of the function will not know how many elements the array contains.

Pay attention to that the function  `nDigits` is also wrong because in the case when zero will be passed to the function that is a valid number the function will return `0` instead of `1`.

Also the program will incorrectly work when the user will supply a negative number. It makes more sense to write a function that converts an integer number to a string. In this case the result string can contain the minus sign.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how such a function can be written.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

size_t nDigits( int n ) 
{
    const int Base = 10;

    size_t count = 0;

    do { ++count; } while ( n /= Base );

    return count;
}

char * createDigitList( int n )
{
    const int Base = 10;
    size_t count = nDigits( n ) + ( n < 0 );

    char *s = calloc( count + 1, sizeof( char ) );

    if ( s != NULL )
    {
        if ( n < 0 ) s[0] = '-';

        do
        {
            int digit = n % Base;
            if ( digit < 0 ) digit = -digit;

            s[--count] = digit + '0';
        } while ( n /= Base );
    }

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "%d is \"%s\"\n", 0, createDigitList( 0 ) );
    printf( "%d is \"%s\"\n", INT_MIN, createDigitList( INT_MIN ) );
    printf( "%d is \"%s\"\n", INT_MAX, createDigitList( INT_MAX ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 is "0"
-2147483648 is "-2147483648"
2147483647 is "2147483647"
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand this in detail, one should understand the C language argument passing concepts. One has to understand **Variable Scope** and the **Pass by value** vs **Pass by Reference** differences. Here is a small intro [on that](https://denniskubes.com/2012/08/20/is-c-pass-by-value-or-reference/)

Additionally, here is one of the way to re-write your program in to a working one.

```
int *createDigitList(int n);
int nDigits(int n);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n = 1234;
    int *digitList;

    digitList = createDigitList(n);
//CALL 2 PRINTF
    printf("Call 2: %d \n", digitList[2]);

    return 0;
}

//returns number of digits (works OK)
int nDigits(int n) {
    int unit;
    int digit = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        unit = n % 10;
        n = (n - unit )/ 10;
        digit++;
    }
    return digit;
}

//Allocates memory for list and puts every digit inside the array list
int *createDigitList(int n) {
    int digit, i;
    int *list;
    list = (int*) malloc(nDigits(n)*sizeof(int));
    for (i = nDigits(n)-1; i >=0; i--) {
        digit = n % 10;
        list[i] = digit;
        n = (n - digit )/ 10;

    }
//CALL 1 PRINTF
    printf("Call 1: %d \n", list[2]);
    return list;
}
```